# How to add different and common classes in radioList() in yii2

Tags: php, arrays, yii2, yii2-model

This is the chtml of radio-button in one of my update form.

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'customer_sel')->radioList(array('customer' => 'Customer', 'supplier' => 'Supplier', 'excludecustomer' => 'Exclude Customer', 'all' => 'All'))->label('Select Choice'); ?>
```

I need to add class names of common(same) and different classes to each radio input.
That is it look like in html...

```
 <div class="form-group field-cashbankentry-customer_sel">
<label class="control-label" for="cashbankentry-customer_sel">Select Choice</label>
<input type="hidden" name="CashBankentry[customer_sel]" value=""><div id="cashbankentry-customer_sel"><label><input type="radio" class="inputbox inputindex_1" name="CashBankentry[customer_sel]" value="customer" checked> Custom</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="inputbox inputindex_2 name="CashBankentry[customer_sel]" value="supplier"> Supplier</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="inputbox inputindex_3 name="CashBankentry[customer_sel]" value="excludecustomer"> Exclude Customer</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="inputbox inputindex_4 name="CashBankentry[customer_sel]" value="all"> All</label></div>
```

i have classes to add [inputbox(common to all)and inputindex_1-4 to each radios]
i'm syntactically confused to add array of classes to this.
How to add these classes to this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'customer_sel')->radioList(array('customer' => 'Customer', 'supplier' => 'Supplier', 'excludecustomer' => 'Exclude Customer', 'all' => 'All'))->label('Select Choice'); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the `item` option for the `radioList` options, you can see the [`Html::activeRadioList()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#activeRadioList()-detail) for details.

The below code should work for you.

```
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'customer_sel')->radioList(
        [
            'customer' => 'Customer',
            'supplier' => 'Supplier',
            'excludecustomer' => 'Exclude Customer',
            'all' => 'All',
        ],
        [
            'item' => function ($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {

                $return = '<label>';
                $return .= '<input class="inputbox inputindex_' . (++$index) . '" type="radio" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value . '" ' . ($checked ? "checked" : "") . '>';
                $return .= ucwords($label);
                $return .= '</label>';
                return $return;
            },

        ]
    )->label('Select Choice');
?>
```

*Note: to make the first option selected by default, you should set the attribute with the value inside the action. like*

```
$model = new CashBankentry();
$model->customer_sel='customer';
```

Comment: Hi Omer - I think I shared a wrong link - here is correct link - https://stackoverflow.com/q/65239734/1124993

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier if you generate the markup without using the `$form->field()` helper. Check its implementation and you will see the different parts you need to code by separate.

A call to `$form->field()` basically calls to `Html::activeLabel()` `Html::activeInput()` and `Html::activeError()`