# YII2 Active Form show custom validation message

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

I have login form which, where I am implementing 2 Factor Authentication integrating twilio API.

The API is working fine and I can get the verification response for success or failure.

Now I am somehow not able to display the message "OTP verification Failed" on the form.

here is my controller code:

public function actionLogin() {

```
    $this->layout = '@app/themes/backend/login';
    $model = new LoginForm(['scenario' => 'login']);
        
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load($_POST)) {
            $authy_id = Yii::$app->session->get('authy_id');
          //  var_dump($authy_id);exit;
          Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        //  var_dump($model);exit;
            if(!empty($authy_id)){                
                $authy_api = new AuthyApi('api-key');
                $token_entered_by_user = $model->otp;
               
                $verification = $authy_api->verifyToken($authy_id, $token_entered_by_user);
                

            if ($verification->ok()) {
                // correct token
              //  Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
                return \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::validate($model);
            }else{
               // Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
                $model->addError('OTP Verification Failed');
              print_r('error');
              Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', "OTP verification failed!");
              
                exit;

            }

            }else{
            Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        return \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::validate($model);
            }
    }
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {                    
                if (Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role == 'admin') {
    
                    $path = "../" . Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role;    
                    return $this->redirect($path);
                } 
                elseif(Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role == 'customer') {
                    $path = "../" . Yii::$app->user->identity->user_role .'/default/index';
                    return $this->redirect($path);
                }
                
                else{
                    $path = "../" . "site/index";
                     return $this->redirect($path);
        ...
        }
        
        
    }
    return $this->render('login', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

and in my view file I have tried like:

```
<?php pjax::begin(['id'=>'otp-error']); ?>
      <?php  if(Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('error')):?>
        <div class="info" id="otp-error">
       
        <?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('error') ?>
        
      </div>
      <?php endif?>
      <?php pjax::end(); ?>
```

what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `exit;` after setting the "OTP verification failed!" message.

You are returning to nowhere just after you set that flash message.

Remember that for the flash message to work, your code must reach your view. If you return before, or return a JSON, it will never get to your client.